# Fat arrow to define a property

Tags: typescript

In type script, property can be defined as

get  someprop(): boolean {return a  === b;}

Is it possible to use arrow operator here ?  something like

get  someprop()  => a === b ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, setter/getter syntax in JavaScript [requires using](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-method-definitions):

```
get propName() {
  // function body
}
```

or

```
set propName() {
  // function body
}
```

There aren't any other options, unfortunately, if you have to use a setter or getter.

Standard properties in an object literal can use arrow functions, of course.

```
const obj = {
  someprop: () => a === b
};
```